# Does adding an adjective before a noun change its article e.g. from zero article to an/a?

Tags: articles

Does adding an adjective before a noun change its article e.g. from a/an to zero?

For example:

> Rotation will cause movement of aircraft parts.

and

> Rotations will cause a vertical movement of aircraft parts.

I don't know whether these sentences are correct in terms of articles, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No need for an a at all.

Comment: All four are acceptable (and I'd not be unhappy with 'the vertical movement ...'). I'd choose the two you suggest as sounding IMO most natural.